# Update fancybox 4 content when filters are applied to a cms list

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, fancybox, lightbox

I have a cms collection list with images. I filter them with mixitup library that's just sets `display:none` to filtered out images. Clicking on any of the collection list thumbnails fires fancybox 4 with the corresponding full res pictures. Inside there you can click through all of the list collection images. Filtering the list works fine.

What I want to do is update fancybox on click of the thumbnail img when some filters are applied, and show only filtered images. Right now Fancybox always shows a full unfiltered set.

It gets assigned to the content like this

```
Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox="gallery"]')
```

I was trying to update Fancybox, looking for elements without `display:none` on click of a filter button

```
let visibleLinks = $('.lightbox-link:not(:hidden)');

$('.lightbox-link').on('click', function() {
      Fancybox.unbind('[data-fancybox="gallery"]');
      Fancybox.bind(visibleLinks);
    });
```

But that, and many other variations, have failed. Would love to get some input from you – how I can update fancybox content?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using your selector directly? like this:

```js
Fancybox.bind('.lightbox-link:not(.hidden)');
```

Because you could read that code snippet in words like this:

`when user clicks any element matching '.lightbox-link:not(.hidden)' selector, start Fancybox and create gallery using elements that match that selector`

and I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for replying Janis! 

Unfortunately when I do
`Fancybox.bind('[data-fancybox="gallery"]:not(:hidden)'`
or
`Fancybox.bind('.lightbox-link:not(:hidden)');`
(in my case both should target the same elements)

Fancybox fires but the layout is broken, and items aren't filtered as I still can see the counter showing the total amount regardless of the filter applied.

Selecting elements outside the fancybox works fine.

Fancybox docs says: "You can choose any CSS selector here to attach click handler to the currently selected set of elements as well as all future matching elements"

Comment: Please, create a demo using any code playground.

Comment: https://codepen.io/baltazar-fajto/pen/vYrNQxm

Comment: You have to use a valid CSS selector. E.g., if `document.querySelectorAll('.lightbox-link:not(:hidden)')` returns collection of links, they will be used to create Fancybox gallery. If it does not return, then you should not expect that Fancybox will do smth. Note: `'.lightbox-link:not(:hidden)'` selector would work only using jQuery or other selector engine.

Comment: Right... I do have jquery installed. I've found a code pen that is able to update fancybox the way I want (https://codepen.io/roman-simlinger/pen/NWXOVJo), but it's tangled in different filtering concepts which makes reverse engineering difficult. The author fires fancybox like this `Fancybox.bind("[data-fancybox].active")` and I'm trying to replicate it, but need to use different logic for applying "active" class; I'm trying to select all .lightbox-link without display:none add "active" there, but I cannot make it work. My code pen: https://codepen.io/baltazar-fajto/pen/bGKVOQV

Comment: In your demo, all your links have class name `active`, therefore fancybox shows all links. If only you could remove that class name from links that should be hidden, it would work. Or, if you could add some class name to parent element, you could use that.